# Using a single button to show and hide text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if this will be a duplicate, but I've tried multiple scripts (not just in jQuery, but also in Javascript) to try to get the job done. Here's the HTML:

```
<p id="text">
  I will disappear!
</p>
<button id="togglebutton">
  Go!
</button>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#togglebutton').click(function() {
    $('text').toggle('slow');
});
```

[Click me to try the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvzyvss4/2/)

I hope you may be able to  find a solution. Thanks :D

Comment: Just add `#` into `text`. `$('#text')`

Comment: Sorry for me being an idiot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `#test` instead of `test` to select an id attribute in jquery

```js
 $('#togglebutton').click(function() {
     $('#text').toggle('slow');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<p id="text">
  I will disappear!
</p>
<button id="togglebutton">
  Go!
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're selecting an ID, `$('text')` should be `$('#text')`

```js
$('#togglebutton').click(function() {
  $('#text').toggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">
  I will disappear!
</p>
<button id="togglebutton">
  Go!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `#` sign for the `text` attribute.

```
$('#togglebutton').click(function() {
    $('#text').toggle('slow');
});
```